# r.ParseForm field order

Tags: go

So I would like to preserve the order of the post fields.
But now using the http `ParseForm` function it will put the fields into a map which will have a different order each time.

The original query : `a=1&b=2&c=3` can become `b=2&c=3&a=1` or any random order.

Since I hash the query and compare it with the hash of the user his query the hash on my side changes all the time since the order of the fields are random.

Code:

```
func parsePostQuery(r *http.Request, hashQuery string) bool {
    urlquery := url.Values{}

    r.ParseForm()

    for k, p := range r.Form {
        urlquery.Set(k, p[0])
    }

    //some psuedo code
    if hashQuery == hash(urlquery.Encode()){
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

How can I parse the fields that are submitted by the user and keep the field order of the user?

Sidenote: I do not know the field names in advance.

Comment: Order the fields alphabetical before calculating the hash.

Comment: @TheHippo You can't. A map never guarantees to preserve order, even after a sort operation. You need a slice or array, which guarantees preservation of order, sort it and access the map via these sorted keys. See below.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I never explicitly said to order the map. ;-)

Comment: @TheHippo Just wanted to make sure nobody falls into the sorted map trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same area as other answers, you will need the clients to calculate their hash by alphabetizing all parameters before hashing. The code you've supplied should work fine; `values.Encode()` will [sort the values by key](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Encode) on it's own:

> Encode encodes the values into “URL encoded” form ("bar=baz&foo=quux") **sorted by key**.

There's no way to preserve the ordering of the client; in fact, what you receive may not even be how it was ordered on the client end. However unlikely, there's no guarantee that intermediate processes won't change things.

Comment: Hmm okay. Thats true. Ill see what i can do to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: You can't implicitly. The [underlying data structure is a map](https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go?s=18971:19022#L651), for which the order is not guaranteed. You need to take additional steps.

However [Go maps in action](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) shows an easy way to access the map in a sorted way. You create a slice of the keys, sort that slice and access the map value by iterating over the keys in the sorted slice.

For your example, it would look something like this

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    // Which is the same structure as url.Values()
    var m map[string][]string = make(map[string][]string)
    m["c"] = []string{"19.95"}
    m["b"] = []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
    m["a"] = []string{"1"}

    // Note that playground is deterministic, so the order should be preserved there
    // However, you can not rely on that in the real world
    fmt.Println("Unsorted")
    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Println("Key:", k, "Value:", v)
    }

    var keys []string
    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)

    hash := md5.New()
    fmt.Println("\nSorted")
    for _, k := range keys {

        fmt.Println("Key:", k, "Value:", m[k])

        // Add Key/Value pair to hash
        fmt.Printf("\tAdding KEY '%s' to hash\n", k)
        io.WriteString(hash, k)
        for _, v := range m[k] {
            fmt.Printf("\tAdding VALUE '%s' to hash\n", v)
            io.WriteString(hash, v)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nHash: %x", hash.Sum(nil))
}
```

<kbd>[Run above code on Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/82vMst0Tnl)</kbd>

Comment: The request of the user isnt sorted. And what you do here is sorting the map using Sort. Its just the particular order the user submits there fields is what i would like to preserve.

Comment: @RoyvanZanten What you described was that you wanted the fields in a *specific* order to be able to create a hash sum. And read the code closely: That's exactly what it does. A request is sent as one, there is no order of fields not should you rely on it. If you need an order, you need to apply one.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the request body and check for the form parameters. They will appear in the same order as in the request(hope your client application is also aware of this order preserving)

You can create a reader for reading the request body. A **sample** code looks like

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Reading Error ")
    return 
}
fmt.Println("Req Body  :  ", string(body))
```

Note : Be aware of the content type